# How can I update a parameter? I have a function and another function should changes/update the value of it

Tags: java

I'm pretty new to Java. For university I should program an atm from which you can only only ask for for the current money on the bankaccount, withdraw money and deposit money. I'm almost done, but I don't know how I can program, that the current money is always updating after withdrawing or depositing money. My code is in german, I hope that is not a problem. **current money on bankaccount** is **getKontostand()**, **Depositing** is **einzahlen()** and
**withdrawing** is **abheben()**, I hope that helps a little with understanding.
My question is how can I let my current money update? So that if I deposit money its also updated in the function that shows the current money?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Konto {
    private static Scanner in;
    private double kontostand;

    public void getKontostand(double kontostand) {

        System.out.println("Ihr Kontostand betraegt " + kontostand + "Euro");
    }

        public void einzahlen (){

            double neuerkontostand = 0;
            double betrag = 0;

            System.out.println("Wie viel möchten Sie einzahlen? Bitte geben Sie den Betrag in EURO an.");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            betrag = sc.nextDouble();


            if (betrag > 0) {
                neuerkontostand= kontostand + betrag;
                kontostand = neuerkontostand;

                System.out.println("Sie haben " + betrag + " Euro erfolgreich eingezahlt.");

            } else {
                System.out.println("Bitte geben Sie den Betrag in Euro an.");
            }
        }

        public void abheben (){

            double neuerkontostand = 0;
            double betrag;

            System.out.println("Wie viel möchten Sie abheben? Bitte geben Sie den Betrag in EURO an.");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            betrag = sc.nextDouble();


            if (betrag < kontostand) {
                neuerkontostand = kontostand - betrag ;
                System.out.println("Sie haben " + betrag + " Euro erfolgreich abgehoben.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Ihr Kontostand reicht leider nicht aus.");
            }
        }

    public void getKontostand() {
    }
}

class Geldautomat {

    private int Auswahl;
    Konto konto1 = new Konto();
    private double kontostand;


    public void menu() {
        do {
            System.out.println("Was möchten Sie tun?");
            System.out.println("(1) Kontostand abfragen.");
            System.out.println("(2) Einen Betrag einzahlen.");
            System.out.println("(3) Einen Betrag auszahlen.");
            System.out.println("(4) Nichts.");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            Auswahl = sc.nextInt();

            if (Auswahl == 1) {
                konto1.getKontostand();
            }
            if (Auswahl == 2) {
                konto1.einzahlen();
            }
            if (Auswahl == 3) {
                konto1.abheben();
            }
            if (Auswahl == 4) {
                System.out.println("Auf Wiedersehen!/n");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Bitte geben Sie eine Zahl zwischen 1-4 an.");
            }
        } while (Auswahl != 4);

    }
}
    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Geldautomat menu1 = new Geldautomat();
            menu1.menu();
            System.out.println(menu1);

        }
    }
```

Comment: `public void getKontostand(double kontostand)` <- getters like this should not have parameters you pass. You after all want that method to tell you the account balance of your Konto object, currently that function just outputs the value you pass to it, which makes little sense. You should remove the argument add the correct return type and work on/return your field `kontostand` as in `return this.kontostand;`

Comment: There is no need for the "neuerKontostand" variable you can directly subtract with kontostand -= betrag.
In your withdraw function you are missing to assign neuerKontastand to kontostand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am confused by your question, because your `einzahlen` method already does what you are asking. Specifically:

```
neuerkontostand = kontostand + betrag;
kontostand = neuerkontostand;
```

The first line reads the current `kontostand`, adds `betrag` and puts the result in a local variable `neuerKontostand`. The second line reads that sum, and puts it back into `kontostand` so any subsequent call to `einzahlen()` uses the updated account balance. If you do that same thing in `auszahlen()` and `getKontostand()`, your program should work.

The reason this works is that `double kontostand` is declared outside the method, which makes the variable `kontostand` available to all methods of the `Konto` object, i.e. all methods share the same variable. If you had declared the variable inside a method instead, the variable would have been specific to an execution of that method, and therefore not accessible by other methods (or other executions of that same method). That is, the following would not work:

```
public void einzahlen() {
    double kontostand;

    double betrag = scanner.nextDouble();

    double neuerKontostand = kontostand + betrag; // compilation error: kontostand read before it is assigned a value
}
```

(by the way, you are declaring `getKontostand()` twice - once without parameters, and once with a parameter. As far as java is concerned, these are two different methods that just happen to have the same name. You probably only want the version without parameters - you can read the current `kontostand` just like `einzahlen()` does.)

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned up your code. I'm there for questions.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program {

    public static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Geldautomat.menu();
    }

    public static class Konto {
        private double kontostand;

        public void printKontostand() {
            System.out.println("Ihr Kontostand betraegt " + kontostand + " Euro");
        }

        public void einzahlen() {

            System.out.println("Wie viel möchten Sie einzahlen? Bitte geben Sie den Betrag in EURO an.");

            while (true) {
                try {
                    double betrag = Double.parseDouble(sc.nextLine());
                    if (betrag > 0) {
                        kontostand += betrag;

                        System.out.println("Sie haben " + betrag + " Euro erfolgreich eingezahlt.");

                        break;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Bitte geben Sie den Betrag in Euro an.");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Bitte geben Sie eine Zahl ein");
                }
            }
        }

        public void abheben() {

            System.out.println("Wie viel möchten Sie abheben? Bitte geben Sie den Betrag in EURO an.");

            while (true) {
                try {
                    double betrag = Double.parseDouble(sc.nextLine());
                    if (betrag < 0) {
                        System.out.println("Bitte geben sie einen positiven Betrag ein");
                    } else if (betrag < kontostand) {
                        kontostand -= betrag;
                        System.out.println("Sie haben " + betrag + " Euro erfolgreich abgehoben.");
                        break;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Ihr Kontostand reicht leider nicht aus.");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Bitte geben Sie eine Zahl ein");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Geldautomat {

        private static Konto konto1 = new Konto();

        public static void menu() {
            int Auswahl = 0;

            do {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Was möchten Sie tun?");
                    System.out.println("(1) Kontostand abfragen.");
                    System.out.println("(2) Einen Betrag einzahlen.");
                    System.out.println("(3) Einen Betrag auszahlen.");
                    System.out.println("(4) Nichts.");

                    Auswahl = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());

                    if (Auswahl == 1) {
                        konto1.printKontostand();
                    }
                    if (Auswahl == 2) {
                        konto1.einzahlen();
                    }
                    if (Auswahl == 3) {
                        konto1.abheben();
                    }
                    if (Auswahl == 4) {
                        sc.close();
                        System.out.println("Auf Wiedersehen!/n");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Bitte geben Sie eine Zahl zwischen 1-4 an.");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Bitte geben Sie eine Zahl zwischen 1-4 ein");
                }
            } while (Auswahl != 4);
        }
    }
}
```